# Pagination in Django-Rest-Framework with API-View

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

It is necessary to display the configured 10 records per swagger page (book api).

The BookListView class in views.py looks like this:

```
class BookListView(APIView):
  def get(self, request):
   author = set([item.get('ID') for item in Author.objects.values('ID').all()])
   saler = set([item.get('name') for item in Saler.objects.values('name').all()])
    if author:
      salers = Saler.objects.filter(name__in=list(saler - author))
    else:
      salers = Saler.objects.all()
    serializer = SalerListSerializer(salers, many = True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now all records are displayed at once, I would like to add pangination and display 10 records on one page.

I added 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.DESIRED_PAGINATION_STYLE', 'PAGE_SIZE': 100 to the settings.py file, but since I am using APIView, this does not work.

What is the way to implement the idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your paginator's `paginate_queryset` method. Since you're using a `APIView`, it does not have many of the built-in functions to do this for you, but the process is as follows:

1. Instantiate a paginator:

```
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings

pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS
paginator = pagination_class()
```

2. Get a page from your queryset and serialize it:

```
page = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view=self)
serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
```

3. Return a paginated response:

```
return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

This is how django-rest does it with its `ListAPIView` class. You can go though the code easily by checking out the `ListAPIView`'s `list` method [here](https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.generics/ListAPIView.html#list).

However, I suggest using a `ListAPIView` instead of an `APIView` since it already handles
pagination for you.